# Java Swing - Combobox with three dots

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, preferredsize

I have a jComboBox in my Swing GUI, filling the value from my SQL Database.

All looks fine but when I run the application, my combobox appeared e.g [Black  ...] with the 3 dots to the side.

Please advice how can I remove the 3 dots.

Edited:
Added code for my jComboBox and a image of it

```
    public void fillTankDepth()
{

    String fill = "Select * from swdepth";
    try{
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(fill);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            String depth = rs.getString("depth");
            comboDepth.addItem(depth);

                        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);    
    }
 }
```

[image]

As per the image above, I've given quite a long width to it yet I'm unable to remove the 3 dots.

Comment: [tag:javascript] tag removed. Java != JavaScript.

Comment: are the 3 dots in the data (in the database)?

Comment: Has your combobox enough width? Maybe it can be caused because of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely aren't providing enough physical room on your GUI to display the data.  Make more horizontal room for your combobox (i.e., make it longer).

**UPDATE**

> As per the image above, I've given quite a long width to it yet I'm unable to remove the 3 dots.

Looking at the screenshot you added, *my guess* is that it's a data problem.  Some jdbc drivers will give you space-padded strings out to the length of the column, even if the data is much shorter.  For example, a column defined as char(10) that has the value "A" in it may come back from your query as

```
"A         "
```

.  If this is the case, trim the strings before adding them to the combo:

```
String depth = rs.getString("depth").trim();
```

Also, as suggested by mKorbel, you can set the prototype for your combo:

```
// if you're using strings, and the max length will be 10
comboDepth.setPrototypeDisplayValue("1234567890");
```

Keep in mind, the padded spaces (as your screenshot suggests) will still be a problem if the spaces are causing the data to be longer than what you're expecting.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: is that implying that I didn't?  His answer is only a suggestion, mind you.  Without a code sample, it could be any one of a number of things.

Comment: @splungebob Yes and no.  You hinted at what what causing the problem, but didn't actually provide an answer as to how to fix it, mKorbel did.  I might argue that it's nothing better then a comment, but does that invalid your answer...I'm not qualified to say - I've certainly not down voted ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I guess I'm not used to how things work on SO. On other forums I've been on, spoon-fed answers were discouraged, especially if it's just a guess.  Again, setPrototypeDisplayValue may or may not fix the OP's problem, but since we don't know (no code was provided), why guess?  Shouldn't we encourage better question-asking instead of throwing darts at potential answers?  Also, I'm unclear about your remark about my post may be "nothing more than a comment".  Are you suggesting only code samples in answers?

Comment: @splungebob Again, yes and no. But `setPrototypeDisplayValue` is the only way to provide sizing hints to the combo box WITHOUT data. It's also means that the combobox doesn't need to traverse the WHOLE model to find the widest value (when available) - You are right, there could be a layout manager issue involved, and this will highlight that.  As I also commented, if you're not 100% sure, then you should leave a comment and as for more information.  You answer is correct - to a point.  mKorbel's comment will most likely fix the problem - IMHO

Comment: Can I have a example of using setPrototypeDisplayValue.